# How to identify a button with a label in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have an application where button Id's keeps on changing.The only thing consistent is the label. EG: the 'Login' label of a button. How can I find a button whose label is 'Login'?
an anybody please help me on this?

Comment: Can you post the markup of the button

Comment: <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" id="dijit_form_Button_0_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" unselectable="on"> <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" id="dijit_form_Button_0_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" unselectable="on"> Text - Sign In

Comment: Try to detect the csspath of the button using firebug. Also check if the login button is present inside a frame.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use xpath?

```
//button[text()='EG']
```

Comment: Hey I tried with WebElement signin_button= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Sign In']")); but it did not workout :(

Comment: Of course the above XPath won't work because you are getting your HTML elements mixed up. You originally told us it's a `button`, thus @TGH has given his solution above, which would work. What you've *actually* shown us, is a `span` (assume it is a `span` just styled to look like a `button`). So what is it *exactly* that you are trying to do?

Comment: I solved that by using:driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#loginForm>div>table>tbody>tr:nth-child(4)>td>div>span>span>span"));